# Applying the axiom of choice in the open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, axiom-of-choice, open-map

I am studying the book by Brézis on functional analysis and I just read the open mapping theorem. The proof is split in two steps. Here is a copy of the step 2:

[image]

I understood the idea of the proof. My problem is formalizing it. I was trying to deduce the existence of the sequence $(z_n)$, and its properties, possibly using recursion, induction and choice. I just asked [a similar question about the Baire theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955404/recursion-and-induction-in-baire-theorem) and it was suggested to me to apply the axiom of dependent choice (DC).

The theorems I have are

> **Thm. 1 (Recursion):** Let $A$ be a set, $a \in A \ $ and $ \ f:A \to A \ $ be a function. Then there exists an unique sequence $ \ b =
> (b_n): \mathbb{N} \to A \ $ such that $ \ b_0=a \ $ and $ \ b_{n+1} =
> f(b_n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> **Thm. 2 (Induction):** Let $ \ K \subset \mathbb{N} \ $ be such that $ \ 0 \in K \ $ and, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $ \ n \in K$, then $ \ n+1 \in K$. Then $ \ K= \mathbb{N}$.

Together with some version of the axiom of choice or DC. This time I am allowed to use DC.

I tryed to define a relation like that in the answer to my last question but I failed because the (n+1)-th choice depends not only on the n-th choice but on all the previous entries. I need hints to find this relation or to try another approach. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other answer was erased. It was wrong? Do I really need CC, DC or AC to find this sequence?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to formalize the application of $\sf DC$ in this proof, then you first need to truly understand what $\sf DC$ means, and more specifically, how it is different than just choosing from a countable family of non-empty sets (countable choice).

The main difference is hinted in the name. **Dependent** Choice. The idea is that each choice you make will be influenced by previous choices, for example, if you have two possible choices for $z_1$, and $\|z_1-z_1'\|>\frac14$, then this means that choosing $z_2$ depends on whether you chose $z_1$ or $z_1'$.

This, in contrast to countable choice, which just tells you to choose without any constraints from a countable family of non-empty sets.

---

So, back to your question. How do we formalize this? Note that the choice, when applying $\sf DC$, is of the following form: Given a "valid" finite sequence $\langle z_1,\ldots,z_n\rangle$, there is some $z$ such that $\langle z_1,\ldots,z_n,z\rangle$ is also "valid", then there is a function $f\colon\Bbb N\to Z$, such that for every $n$, $f\restriction\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a "valid" sequence.

(Here "valid" is whatever type of object that you're looking for.)

So all you need to do is argue why when given a sequence of $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ which satisfy the conditions, you can find *an* extension by some arbitrary vector. Then you can apply $\sf DC$.

If you want to use the axiom of choice in full, which does make this slightly clearer (as it imbues the proof of $\sf DC$ from $\sf AC$), simply fix for every finite "valid" sequence of vectors the set of possible extensions by a single vector, then show these are non-empty, and then fix a choice function.

Now by recursion, choose using this choice function. But instead of considering a function $f\colon E\to E$, here you consider a $A$ to be the set of all finite "valid" sequences, and you consider this choice function as a function from $A$ to itself.

Answer (score 1):

${\LARGE [1]} \quad $ Let $$X = \left\{ (u^1,...,u^n) \in \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} E^j \ \ : \ \ \Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j=1}^n u^j \right) \Bigg\Vert_F < \frac{c}{2^n} \right\} \ . $$ By (12) we have that $ \ z_1 \in X \ \Rightarrow \ X \neq \varnothing$.

${\LARGE [2]} \quad $ Define a relation $ \ R \subset X \times X \ $ such that $ \ (u^1,...,u^n)R(v^1,...,v^m) \ $ if, and only if, $$m=n+1 \ , \quad (u^1,...,u^n)=(v^1,...,v^n) \ , \quad \displaystyle \Vert v^m \Vert_E < \frac{1}{2^m}$$ and $$\Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j=1}^n u^j \right) - T(v^m) \Bigg\Vert_F < \frac{c}{2^m} \ \ . $$ The construction above shows that $ \ z_1Rz_2 \ $.

${\LARGE [3]} \quad $ Let $ \ u=(u^1,...,u^n) \in X \ $ and $ \ \displaystyle w = 2^{n+1} \cdot \left[ y - T \left( \sum_{j=1}^n u^j \right) \right]$. Then $$ \lVert w \rVert_F = 2^{n+1} \cdot \Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j=1}^n u^j \right) \Bigg\Vert_F < 2^{n+1} \cdot \frac{c}{2^n} = 2c \ \Rightarrow \ w \in B_F (0_F,2c) \subset \overline{T[B_E(0_E,1)]} \ . $$ Therefore $ \ B_F \left( w, \frac{c}{2^{n+1}} \right) \cap T[B_E(0_E,1)] \neq \varnothing$. Thus there exists $ \ z \in B_E(0_E,1) \ $ such that $ \ T(z) \in B_F \left( w, \frac{c}{2^{n+1}} \right)$. Hence $ \ \lVert z \rVert_E <1 \ $ and $ \ \lVert w - T(z) \rVert_F < \frac{c}{2^{n+1}} \ $. Let $$\xi = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot z \ . $$ Then $ \ \lVert \xi \rVert_E < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \ $ and $$\Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j=1}^n u^j \right) - T(\xi) \Bigg\rVert_F = \Bigg\lVert \left( \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot w \right) - T \left( \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot z \right) \Bigg\rVert_F =$$ $$= \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot \lVert w - T(z) \rVert_F < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{c}{2^{n+1}} < \frac{c}{2^{n+1}} \ . $$ So, $(u^1,...,u^n,\xi) \in X \ $ and $ \ (u^1,...,u^n)R(u^1,...,u^n,\xi) \ \Rightarrow \ u=(u^1,...,u^n) \in dom(R)$. We conclude that $ \ dom(R)=X$.

${\LARGE [4]} \quad $ By DC, there exists $ \ (\alpha_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \in X^{\mathbb{N}^*} \ $ such that $ \ \alpha_1 = z_1 \ $ and $ \ \alpha_n R \alpha_{n+1} \ $, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

Let $ \ K = \big\{ k \in \mathbb{N}^* : \alpha_k \in E^k \big\}$. Then $ \ \alpha_1 = z_1 \in E = E^1 \ \Rightarrow \ 1 \in K$. Let $ \ k \in K$. Then $ \ \alpha_k \in E^k \ $, say $ \ \alpha_k = \big( \alpha_k^1 , ... , \alpha_k^k \big)$. We have $ \ \alpha_k R \alpha_{k+1} \ $, with $ \ \displaystyle \alpha_{k+1} \in X \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} E^j \ $. So, there exists $ \ j \in \mathbb{N}^* \ $ such that $ \ \alpha_{k+1} \in E^j \ $, say $ \ \alpha_{k+1} = \big( \alpha_{k+1}^1 , ... , \alpha_{k+1}^j \big)$. Therefore $ \ \big( \alpha_k^1 , ... , \alpha_k^k \big) R \big( \alpha_{k+1}^1 , ... , \alpha_{k+1}^j \big) \ \Rightarrow \ j=k+1 \ \Rightarrow \alpha_{k+1} \in E^{k+1} \ \Rightarrow \ k+1 \in K$. By induction, $K= \mathbb{N}^*$, ie, $\alpha_n \in E^n \ $, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. We write $ \ \alpha_n = \big( \alpha_n^1, \alpha_n^2,..., \alpha_n^{n-1},\alpha_n^n \big)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

${\LARGE [5]} \quad $ For each $ \ n \in \mathbb{N}^* \ $ and each $ \ j \in \{ 1,...,n \}$, let $ \ \pi_n^j : E^n \to E \ $ be the projection onto the $j$-th coordinate of $E^n$, ie, $\pi_n^j (u^1,...,u^n) = u^j$, $\forall (u^1,...,u^n) \in E^n$. For each $ \ n \in \mathbb{N^*}$, let $$z_n = \pi_n^n (\alpha_n) = \pi_n^n \big( \alpha_n^1 , ... , \alpha_n^n \big) = \alpha_n^n \ . $$ Note that this notation is coherent with $ \ \alpha_1 = \alpha_1^1 = z_1 \ $ chosen above. We will show that the sequence $ \ (z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} = (\alpha_n^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \in E^{\mathbb{N}^*} \ $ is the desired one.

${\LARGE [6]} \quad $ First let $ \ L = \{ \ell \in \mathbb{N}^* : \alpha_{\ell} = (z_1 , ... , z_{\ell}) \}$. By the last paragraph, $1 \in L$. Let $ \ \ell \in L$. Then $ \ \alpha_{\ell} = (z_1 , ... , z_{\ell})$. We have $ \ \alpha_{\ell +1} = \big(  \alpha_{\ell +1}^1 , ... , \alpha_{\ell +1}^{\ell} , \alpha_{\ell +1}^{\ell +1} \big)$, with $ \ \alpha_{\ell} R \alpha_{\ell +1} \ $, that is, $(z_1 , ... , z_{\ell}) R \big(  \alpha_{\ell +1}^1 , ... , \alpha_{\ell +1}^{\ell} , \alpha_{\ell +1}^{\ell +1} \big) \ \Rightarrow \ (z_1 , ... , z_{\ell}) = \big(  \alpha_{\ell +1}^1 , ... , \alpha_{\ell +1}^{\ell} \big) \ $ and, by definition, $z_{\ell +1} = \alpha_{\ell +1}^{\ell +1} \ . $ So, $ \ \alpha_{\ell +1} = (z_1 , ... , z_{\ell} , z_{\ell +1}) \ \Rightarrow \ \ell +1 \in L$. By induction, $L = \mathbb{N}^*$, ie, $\alpha_n = (z_1 , ... , z_n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

${\LARGE [7]} \quad $ Now let $$K = \left\{ k \in \mathbb{N}^* \ : \ \lVert z_k \rVert_E < \frac{1}{2^k} \ \text{ and } \ \Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{k} z_j \right) \Bigg\rVert_F < \frac{c}{2^k} \right\} \ . $$ By Brézis above, we have that $ \ \lVert z_1 \rVert_E < \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^1} \ $ and $ \ \Bigg\lVert y- T \left( \sum_{j=1}^{1} z_j \right) \Bigg\rVert_F = \lVert y - T(z_1) \rVert_F < \frac{c}{2} = \frac{c}{2^1} \ $. Wich implies $ \ 1 \in K$. Let $ \ k \in K$. Then $ \ \lVert z_k \rVert_E < \frac{1}{2^k} \ $ and $ \ \Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{k} z_j \right) \Bigg\rVert_F < \frac{c}{2^k} \ . $ By $[4]$ and $[6]$ we have $ \ \alpha_k R \alpha_{k+1} \ $, $ \alpha_k = (z_1 , ... , z_k) \ $ and $ \ \alpha_{k+1} = (z_1 , ... , z_k , z_{k+1})$. So, by $[2]$, $(z_1 , ... , z_k) R (z_1 , ... , z_k , z_{k+1}) \ \Rightarrow \ \lVert z_{k+1} \rVert_E < \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \ $ and $$\Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{k+1} z_j \right) \Bigg\rVert_F = \Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{k} z_j \right) - T(z_{k+1}) \Bigg\rVert_F < \frac{c}{2^{k+1}} \ . $$ Hence $ \ k+1 \in K$. By induction, $K = \mathbb{N}^*$, ie, the sequence $ \ (z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \in E^{\mathbb{N}^*} \ $ is such that $$\lVert z_{n} \rVert_E < \frac{1}{2^{n}} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \Bigg\lVert y - T \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{n} z_j \right) \Bigg\rVert_F < \frac{c}{2^{n}} \ , $$ forall $ \ n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila, is my proof correct?

Comment: I didn't check the functional theoretic part, but the appeal to DC seems okay after a cursory glance. (I'm sorry, I don't have time to read through the details right now...)